# jQuery is not generating any Output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to create this simple effect but its not generating any output. Please tell me why its not working.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >
</head>



    <body>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="table.js" ></script>




    <div class="table">
    <p>MyPara</p>
    <p>MyPara2</p>
    <p>MyPara3</p>
    </div>

    </body>
```

table.js

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('table').addClass('highlight');
});
```

Stylesheet

```
.highlight
{
    background-color:#999;


    }
```

Comment: `$('.table')` add the `.` sinc it is a class name, you can use `div.table` too. refer the jquery selectors in their website

Comment: 4 answers and 1 comment within one minute, and they all give the correct answer! Upvotes for everyone!

Comment: Thanks everyone. I can't vote up. It requires 15 rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `.` before class name. Here you are missing it. Your code should be like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.table').addClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `.` for class, change:

```
$('table').addClass('highlight');
```

to

```
$('.table').addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 3):

[class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
 $('.table').addClass('highlight');
```

`$('.table')` ->element with class table

like-wise if you want to use id-selector you can use

`$('#table')` ->element with id table

Answer (score 2):

`table` is a class name , so :

```
$('.table').addClass('highlight');
```

Have some reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html

Answer (score 2):

Use Class Selector

```
$('.table').addClass('highlight');
```

and http is missing so use

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic selectors in jQuery are three: class,ID and tagname.

```
$(".table") // will select the dom elements with table class
$("#table") // will select the dom element with table id
$("table") // will select the table elements
```

In your case, you should use the class selector.

However, jQuery will not cause any error or warning if the selector will not match with any element of the dom. If you expect to find at least one matching element, you can check explicitly this condition testing the size of the object.

To check the size of a jQuery object you can use the .size() function if you are using jQuery <1.8

```
//.size() DEPRECATED IN JQUERY 1.8+
var $table = $(".table");
if($table.size()==0){
    //manage it
}
```

Or the .length property if you are using jQuery 1.8+

```
var $table = $(".table");
if($table.length==0){
    //manage it
}
```

**References**

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- http://api.jquery.com/size/
- http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 0):

`table` is your class name so it should not be

`$('table').addClass('highlight');

above one represent/pointing html  tag`

it should be

`$('.table').addClass('highlight');`